# How can I use ember data set the belongs to relationship?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I look at this guide to use ember data set the relationship, between two model. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/

But it could not work! My code is:

QuotationsNewController:

```
App.QuotationsNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  content: []

  actions:
    save: ->
      quotation =
        actualNumber: @get('actualNumber')
      quotation = @store.createRecord('quotation', quotation)
      @store.find('user', @get('userId')).then (user)->
        quotation.set('user', user)
      quotation.save().then(@onDidCreate.bind(@))
      @set('quotation', '')

  onDidCreate: (quotation)->
    @store.push 'quotation', quotation.get('data')
    @transitionToRoute 'quotation', quotation
```

QuotationsNewRoute:

```
App.QuotationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller)->
    controller.set('users', @store.find('user'))
    controller.set('userId', @auth.get('userId'))
```

Template new:

```
<form {{action 'save' on="submit"}} class="form-horizontal label-left">
  ...
  <div class="controls form-group">
    {{select-input valueBinding="userId"
                   contentBinding="users"
                   optionValuePath="content.id"
                   optionLabelPath="content.name"
                   class="select-block-level"}}
  </div>
</form>
```

Quotation Model:

```
App.Quotation = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  user: DS.belongsTo 'user'
```

User Model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  quotations: DS.hasMany('quotation', async: true)
```

Version:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.f482da04 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I think it can set the user and quotation relationship, but I see the user alway is null `"user_id"=>nil`. I don't know why the user_id alway is nil.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same exact problem and I believe it's because of my active model serializer having issues with has_one associations.

Comment: @arinh Sorry. Because so many problem, I am not using ember data now. So I do not know how to fix this problem. But Ember Data will release after a few day, I think will be better.